# How to display x elements with for loop in vue.js

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, vue.js

I have this for loop in my asp.net page, then in the same site I have to do the same but in vue.js, I'm not familiar with vue I've check the v-for but I can't manage to get the same result, can someone show me the right way please?

This is my for loop in asp.net, I just need to translate this in vue.js :

```
<div>
@for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
if (i <= (rating))
{
    <i class="icon-ned icon-ned-star red"></i>
}
else
{
    <i class="icon-ned icon-ned-star gray"></i>
}
}
</div>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you checked vue documentation, its well written.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range

```
<div>
  <i 
   v-for="n in 5"
   class="icon-ned icon-ned-start"
   :class="{
     'red': n <= rating,
     'gray': n > rating
   }"
  ></i>
</div>
```

or `:class="n <= rating ? 'red' : 'gray'"` for classes list with toggling

Comment: OP also wants to add grey and red icons based on `rating`

Comment: Edited answer with icons and colors

Comment: ok I see, the thing is that it's a 5 stars rating, so if I have 4/5 the last star should be other color

Comment: I must have something wrong in the syntaxe, I'm getting this in the page 
<= rating ? 'red' : '', n > rating ? 'gray' : ''] >
do you know why?

Comment: You don't need to use array syntax there, use previously mentioned `:class="n <= rating ? 'red' : 'gray'"`. Of course be sure if "rating" is defined for you

Comment: @novoa I missed that in the edit, sorry. Forgot quotes in the array syntax : `:class = "[icon-ned, icon-ned-start, n <= rating ? 'red' : '', n > rating ? 'gray' : '']"`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and fixed it like you see below;

**Please Note** that I am using google material icons for this purpose and tailwind for the styling. but either way this will still work with plain CSS just make sure you declare the classes you are aiming at correctly;

Here you go:

```
<span 
 v-for="n in 5"
 :key="n"
 :class=" 
   n <= rating 
     ? 'text-yellow-400 material-icons' 
     : 'text-gray-300 material-icons'
    ">
 star 
 </span>
```